# Data Dictionary - beginners

Tags: mysql, database, dictionary

I am just learning about data dictionary's and I can't find the answer to one question and I am stuck on it.

**Q~ Apparently the date/time data types come with a default string.  Why do you think this is so?**

Below is the link to the data-dictionary image:

[image]

Comment: 1. Give some context, eg "I got this question as feedback from the  pic I produced from the following spec ..." or "I was given this pic and this question ..." 2. Say what you think the question means. 3. Say what you think the answer might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the correct answer...

The main reason is due to the database defaulting to start of EPOCH if the date isn’t specified during an insert statement, i.e. 1980-01-01 00:00:00. By setting it to be 0000-00-00 it means that it will always generate a default date of that instead, as the 1980 date is a real date and the 0000 one isn’t it makes it easier to check if the date has been entered/updated already and provide the user with appropriate options based on that.